# How can I set up redux-observable with redux-toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux-observable, redux-toolkit

I am unable to set up redux-observable in my current project. So far, I've been using redux-toolkit for everything redux related, but now when I try to add redux-observable I get this error:

[image]

This is how I set it up:

```
function logEpic(actions) {
  return actions.pipe(tap(console.log), ignoreElements())
}

const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware()

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    data: dataReducer,
    dashboard: dashboardReducer,
    error: errorReducer,
    login: loginReducer,
    authentication: authenticationReducer,
  },
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(epicMiddleware),
})

epicMiddleware.run(logEpic)
```

Here is the callstack:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurred due to incompatability with RxJS7. Downgraded to 6.6.7 and it seems to be working fine now.